# Правильная настройка sendmail на сервер

Tags: email, sendmail

В общем есть сервер на Debian, там есть PHP и sendmail, отправка почты с PHP через sendmail худо-бедно настроена.Письма с сервера отправляются от имени root@domain.com по-умолчанию, если в mail() не указывать заголовок From.А если задать дополнительный заголовок From, например info@domain.com, то письма приходят либо от root@domain.com, либо от info@, но с совершенно каким-то левым доменом после @ (и естественно попадает в спам).

Получать почту на сервере не нужно, нужно только чтобы она нормально отправлялась. Собственно 2 вопроса в итоге:

1. как поменять пользователя (ящик) по-умолчанию (чтобы не от root@domain.com отправлялись письма, а с ящика поприличнее на том же домене)?
2. как настроить отправку писем с любого ящика на этом домене (*@domain.com), то есть чтоб они приходили от соответствующего ящика (info@domain.com, admin@domain.com)?

Comment: занесите www-data в trusted users, если у вас там и правда sendmail

Answer (score 3):

Для начала надо почитать как вызывать функцию `mail()` в РНР.
Дальше делаем такой вызов:

```
mail('someuser@example.net', $subj, $mailbody, $additional_headers, '-f from@domain.com');
```

Здесь очень важен параметр `-f` - т.к. именно он задает от какого пользователя уйдет почта.